# Perform class methods on a casted object

Tags: c#, asp.net, optimization

I have the following code:

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime)rdr["DateFromSQLDB"];
genericclass.classpropertystring = dt.ToShortDateString();
```

How can I condense this to a single line?

Here is the class...

```
public class genericclass
{
    public string classpropertystring { get; set; }
}
```

It works great as it is, but I want to be able to use something like:

```
genericclass.classpropertystring = (DateTime)rdr["DateFromSQLDB"].ToShortDateString();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks everyone. Was missing `()`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
genericclass.classpropertystring = ((DateTime)rdr["DateFromSQLDB"]).ToShortDateString();
```

However, doing it this way makes the code less readable, so I would keep it like you have it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

U just miss 2 parentheses:

```
genericclass.classpropertystring = ((DateTime)rdr["DateFromSQLDB"]).ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to make sure that you qualify the object first:

```
genericclass.classpropertystring = ((DateTime)rdr["DateFromSQLDB"]).ToShortDateString();
```

By adding the parentheses around the cast, you are able to treat everything inside as the `DateTime` type.

I agree with @adrianbanks though, I prefer the readability of your first example.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DbDataReader.GetDateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.getdatetime.aspx) instead:

```
genericclass.classpropertystring = rdr.GetDateTime(rdr.GetOrdinal("DateFromSQLDB")).ToShortDateString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to condense it? It makes it harder to read.  Also what if the rdr object returned is null?  It will blow up.  I would try something that was a little more robust to handle potential bad values.  While it takes more code you will handle more situations without having a bunch of try catch blocks all over the place.

```
public static void DoSomething()
    {
        using (var connection =new SqlConnection("constring"))
        {
            var command = new SqlCommand("myquery", connection);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                var mc = new MyClass();
                var mydate = rdr["DateFromSQLDB"];
                if (mydate != null)
                {
                    DateTime date;
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(mydate.ToString(), out date))
                    {
                        mc.MyDateProperty = date.ToShortDateString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wanted less code, not more. In my case `DateFromSQLDB` is not a nullable value, if there are rows there is a valid date. I do indeed use a single `try/catch` and a `while (rdr.Read())` The code above is just a simplified version for SO readability. I was not your downvoter, I do appreciate the feedback. Thanks.